# Get the last element from Apache Spark SQL split() Function

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to get the last element from the Array that return from Spark SQL split() function.

```
split(4:3-2:3-5:4-6:4-5:2,'-')
```

I know it can get by

```
split(4:3-2:3-5:4-6:4-5:2,'-')[4]
```

But i want another way when i don't know the length of the Array .
please help me.

Comment: in `List` you can use `last`

Comment: you mean like this. last(split(4:3-2:3-5:4-6:4-5:2,'-')).i tried it.but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an UDF to do that, as follow:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1L,"one-last1"), (2L,"two-last2"), (3L,"three-last3"))).toDF("key","Value")
+---+-----------+
|key|Value      |
+---+-----------+
|1  |one-last1  |
|2  |two-last2  |
|3  |three-last3|
+---+-----------+

val get_last = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => Try(xs.last).toOption)

val with_just_last = df.withColumn("Last" , get_last(split(col("Value"), "-")))
+---+-----------+--------+
|key|Value      |Last    |
+---+-----------+--------+
|1  |one-last1  |last1   |
|2  |two-last2  |last2   |
|3  |three-last3|last3   |
+---+-----------+--------+
```

Remember that the **split** function from SparkSQL can be applied to a column of the DataFrame.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.i'm using java.i'll try it on java.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use SparkSql Reverse() function on a column after Split(). 
For example:

`SELECT reverse(split(MY_COLUMN,'-'))[0] FROM MY_TABLE`

Here `[0]` gives you the first element of the reversed array, which is the last element of the initial array.

Comment: Great suggestion! Better than accepted answer in imho, since it is portable and doesn't require UDFs.

Comment: Absolutely the best answer, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Please check [substring_index](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring_index) it should work exactly as you want:

```
substring_index(lit("1-2-3-4"), "-", -1) // 4
```

Comment: Usage of -1 is specify in the docs of `substring_index` so this should be even better than a reverse and split

Answer (score 0):

use split(MY_COLUMN,'-').getItem(0) if you are using Java

Comment: That's how you get the first element. OP asks for last one