# split column and get last element spark dataset

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I wrote the following code:

```
def extractGenderFromName(ds: Dataset[Toto])
                          (implicit sparkSession: SparkSession): Dataset[Toto] = {
    if (ds("gender") == null)
      ds.withColumn("gender", split(col(identity), "/")(1))
}
```

Here I want to get the last part of the split of col `identity`, I put `1` but it can be `2` or `3`. How to dynamically take the last part of col `identity`?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868166/get-the-last-element-from-apache-spark-sql-split-function)

Answer (score 1):

Use `element_at` function with negative index `-1` for last element of an array column. Also, you need to use `when` expression to check whether the column `gender` is null, not Scala if-statement:

```scala
ds.withColumn(
  "gender",
  when(
    col("gender").isNull, 
    element_at(split(col("identity"), "/"), -1)
  ).otherwise(col("gender"))
)
```

Note that you can actually use `substring_index` function without having to split the column `identity` like this:

```scala
substring_index(col("identity"), "/", -1)
```