# Pyspark- how to reformat column names from schema description

Tags: python, string, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to get the column names of a table and only extract the last part after `_` For example for column name `a_col_name1`, I'd like to keep `name1`

Below is the code I tried, and the part doesn't work. Could someone please help with this? Please let me know if I could explain this better. Many thanks.

```
df = spark.sql("describe mytable") #get the schema of the dataframe

#trying to concat the last part of col names after "_" into a string 
col_names = ",".join([n["col_name"] for n in df.collect()]) #this works without subtring

#.split("_",len([n["col_name"] -1) this part trying to get substring is not successful
col_names_short= ",". join([n["col_name"].split("_",len([n["col_name"] -1) for n in df.collect()]) #this doesn't work
```

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868166/get-the-last-element-from-apache-spark-sql-split-function

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do it in spark sql

Comment: what's the issue being faced? are you not able to get the correct names, or not able to rename the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.columns`.

```
list(map(lambda c: c.split('_')[-1], df.columns))
# ['name1', 'name2']
```